# What are the crewing requirements for a B787 flying LAX to SIN?

Tags: pilots, crew

I’m wondering what the crew size, and rest requirements for the flight crew of a Boeing 787-9 flying [LAX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Los_Angeles_International_Airport) to [SIN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singapore_Changi_Airport) (Flight number UA37).

Comment: To save you the Google, it's an LAX-SIN flight on a Boeing 787-9 with flight times of around 17 and a half hours.

Comment: Welcome to Aviation.SE, may I invite you to take the [tour](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/tour) and read the [help] so you can get to known the site? You're original question is likely to be closed as `too broad` or `off topic` as different air craft could be used for that flight, I will suggest an edit which I think will improve the question. You can also edit the question to improve it after.

Comment: @downvoters yes this isn't a perfect first question but this is a new user, do you think we could try helping them rather than penalising them for being new and not knowing the site?

Answer (score 1):

I can't provide a specific answer but rest times are contract matter and airline specific. Also, most curiously, you won't find rest crews on private jets.

Depending on the airline you will have anything between 3 and 5 pilots on longer flights (anything above 8h). Three being the most common. Start and landing are handled by captain and co pilot, in between the aircraft is flown by a "cruise pilot" of a lower rank.

Rest crew regulations can cause problems, if there is a delay. Even a small delay may cause to require a standby crew, which will incur a further delay.

As a rule of thumb, airlines have around 10 flight crews *per aircraft* to allow for relief crews, training, holidays, ...